# Extract Sound Wave

Tags: audio, image-processing

I am looking for a Software from which I can Extract the Sound Waves to be used in a Graphic Software. It is basically for gifting to someone. Can someone guide me in right direction? A command line tool should also be just fine.

Comment: Do you want to export the whole sound wave to an image? Even for one second of sound that makes a very big image. Or are you OK with only 1000 pixels?

Comment: I came across this recently so haven't used it yet but the html 5 web audio api might be able to help https://css-tricks.com/introduction-web-audio-api/

Answer (score 1):

The FFmpeg [showwavespic](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-showwavespic) filter can produce an image of the waveform of an audio input and has a few parameters to customize the output.

Here's an example invocation (from the above link) :

```
ffmpeg -i audio.flac -lavfi showwavespic=split_channels=1:s=1024x800 waveform.png
```

Example output:
[image]

More examples and documentation: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform